# Blank page for disabled products - Compilation enabled - Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, page

Trying to solve a long standing issue on Magento 1.9.2.2 with Compilation Enabled.
**To replicate**
Run and Enable Compilation.
Make any product disabled.
Viewing disabled product URL on frontend produces a blank page - should return a 404.

This produces no PHP errors, system logs or error reports.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Could not reproduce  it - getting 404. Therefore I think you have some kind of error. Can you uncomment errors suppressing in the index ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Already uncommented.  Have added
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler"); and this produced the following: Array
(
    [type] => 64
    [message] => Cannot redeclare class Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs
    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/hejhog.net/httpdocs/magento2/includes/src/__catalog.php
    [line] => 77
)  Downloaded complete src folder and there are 2 instances of the class Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs being declared.  One in __catalog.php and one in Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs.php

Comment: Hello @hejhog, I am also getting blank page for disabled product, How do I get what error my system produce on product page?

Comment: Hello @Vinaya Maheshwari, Never resolved but this must be linked to the declaration of class Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs.  Compile and download your src file.  I would be interested to know if you can find 2 instances of the above class.  Have been running without compilation for months. There appears to be minimal (maybe no) performance benefit of running with compilation enabled.  However, I do like to correct bugs so it would be good to find the solution.

Comment: Hello @hejhog, I have resolved the issue, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for this issue, either disable Magento compiler or pollute your local code pool with autoloader modified to use `include_once`, instead of `include` used by built in autoloader.

Reference :
http://www.techytalk.info/blank-product-page-magento-compilation/

Comment: Thanks.  For completeness.  lib/Varien/Autoload.php  find static public function registerScope($code)  Change include to include_once  Upload to local code - app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php